# how do i figure out what to do with this? flutter local notification or firebase notification

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification, flutter-notification

Hi i am making a workspace managment booking application and I dont know whether to use push notifcation or local notifcation, The situation is that lets say the manager is allowed to book seats and meeting rooms for his team and they should also reach the notifcation that a meeting room is booked. And i have lets say the admin added events from the backend all the users should get a notfication. I am using postgres as my database and nestjs for backend, flutter for app development. I am confused whether to use local or firebase for this application because the notifcations are going to be triggered at time intervals.

I didnt try either since i am in two minds about it and i need some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you know ahead of time when the notification needs to be displayed and the exact contents of the message, using a local notification makes most sense - as it reduces the chance of delivery problems at the exact time that you want to display the notification.

So:

- Synchronize the information that needs to be displayed to the device that needs to display it when you know that information. You can do this through an FCM **data* message, but other mechanisms are fine too.
- Then display the message as a local notification when it is needed.